# Having trouble displaying an image using react-simple-file-upload

Tags: reactjs, image, heroku, state

I am trying to create a small gallery of uploaded images using Heroku's simple-file-upload technique. I've managed to upload and save the images to the database, however I am having a hard time making the gallery with the pictures. Ideally, I'd like to upload a photo and have it saved on the page. Here is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import SimpleFileUpload, { SimpleFileUploadProvider } from "../components/SimpleFileUpload"
import { useState } from 'react'

const API_KEY = '...'


export default function About() {

  const [file, setFile] = useState()

  displayImage = (file) => {

    return file.map((file, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="file-display">
        <h3>{file}</h3>
      </div>
    ))
  };
  
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>upload an image</h1>
      <SimpleFileUpload apiKey={API_KEY} onSuccess={setFile} />
      {file && <p> Uploaded: {file}</p>}
      <div className="gallery-">
        {this.displayImage(this.state.file)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm trying to use state for the gallery with the displayImage funcion, but I keep getting this error.

```
 Line 12:3:  'displayImage' is not defined  no-undef
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you declaring a variable (`displayImage`), you should put for example `const` keyword. Or your snippet is missing something?

Comment: @KiraLT Hey, snippet isn't missing anything. I'm pretty new at this and am following a guide for a blogpost app. I added ```const``` and am now getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayImage' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few issues with your code:

1. When declaring a new variable, you must use `const`, `let` or `var` keyword:

```
const displayImage = (file) => {}
```

2. You can't use (in your case) `this` keyword in the function:

Replace `this.displayImage` to `displayImage`. And `this.state.file` to just `file`.

3. By default `useState` value is undefined. So in your case you must check if `file` is defined:

```js
{file && <div className="gallery-">
        {displayImage(file)}
</div>}
```

4. Class name `gallery-` - you probably missed something here.

Comment: Thank you for this. I greatly appreciate it. Why is "this" not required in this scenario? It's been confusing me when to use it vs. when not to

Comment: `this` is required only for class variables. In your case, you don't even have a class, just a normal function.